# Abandoned Pooled Connection in Grails 2.5.1

Tags: tomcat, grails, connection-pooling

I keep getting this Abandoned Pooled Connection warning in tomcat no matter what I changed in configuration. This actually causing some requests to return 500 Internal server error.

Exception:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.suspect Connection has been marked suspect, possibly abandoned PooledConnection[com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@168cbcd8][74090 ms.]:java.lang.Exception
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getThreadDump(ConnectionPool.java:1052)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:768)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:186)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:403)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor343.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindAllByPersistentMethod$1.doInHibernate(FindAllByPersistentMethod.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.executeFind(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.FindAllByPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternalWithExpressions(FindAllByPersistentMethod.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.java:544)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractClausedStaticPersistentMethod.java:418)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractStaticPersistentMethod.java:72)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FinderMethod$invoke$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:102)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1044.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.call(GormStaticApi.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureStaticMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureStaticMetaMethod.java:62)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.onestopparking.domain.user.User.getAuthorities(User.groovy:59)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1119.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.proxy.GroovyAwareJavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(GroovyAwareJavassistLazyInitializer.java:193)
    at com.onestopparking.domain.user.User_$$_javassist_77.getAuthorities(User_$$_javassist_77.java)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1178.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1847)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1153)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3737)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1165)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
    at com.onestopparking.controller.ReservationController.checkUpdateReservation(ReservationController.groovy:384)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1177.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at com.onestopparking.controller.ReservationController.mail(ReservationController.groovy:270)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1219.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:375)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:205)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:178)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:216)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My DataSource:

```
 dataSource {

 dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', '' 

 pooled = true 

 logSql = true 

 dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" 




 properties { 

 // Documentation for Tomcat JDBC Pool 

 // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes 

 // https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html 

 jmxEnabled = true 

 initialSize = 34 

 maxActive = 377 

 minIdle = 89 

 maxIdle = 233 

 maxWait = 10000 

 maxAge = 10 * 60000 

 timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 34000 

 minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 55000 

 validationQuery = "SELECT 1" 

 validationQueryTimeout = 3 

 validationInterval = 34 

 testOnBorrow = true 

 testWhileIdle = true 

 testOnReturn = false 

 ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad = true 

 // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JDBC_interceptors 

 jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)" 

 defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED // safe default 

 // controls for leaked connections 

 abandonWhenPercentageFull = 100 // settings are active only when pool is full 

 removeAbandonedTimeout = 120 

 removeAbandoned = true 

 // use JMX console to change this setting at runtime 

 logAbandoned = true // causes stacktrace recording overhead, use only for debugging 

 // JDBC driver properties 

 // Mysql as example 

 dbProperties { 

 // Mysql specific driver properties 

 // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html 

 // let Tomcat JDBC Pool handle reconnecting 

 autoReconnect=true//false 

 // truncation behaviour 

 jdbcCompliantTruncation=false 

 // mysql 0-date conversion 

 zeroDateTimeBehavior='convertToNull' 

 // Tomcat JDBC Pool's StatementCache is used instead, so disable mysql driver's cache 

 cachePrepStmts=false 

 cacheCallableStmts=false 

 // Tomcat JDBC Pool's StatementFinalizer keeps track 

 dontTrackOpenResources=true 

 // performance optimization: reduce number of SQLExceptions thrown in mysql driver code 

 holdResultsOpenOverStatementClose=true 

 // enable MySQL query cache - using server prep stmts will disable query caching 

 useServerPrepStmts=false 

 // metadata caching 

 cacheServerConfiguration=true 

 cacheResultSetMetadata=true 

 metadataCacheSize=100 

 // timeouts for TCP/IP 

 connectTimeout=15000 

 socketTimeout=120000 

 // timer tuning (disable) 

 maintainTimeStats=false 

 enableQueryTimeouts=false 

 // misc tuning 

 noDatetimeStringSync=true 

 } 

 }
```

and Here is my server.xml

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"

              name="jdbc/osp"

              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"

              testWhileIdle="true"

              testOnBorrow="true"

              testOnReturn="false"

              validationQuery="SELECT 1"

              validationInterval="30000"

              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"

              maxActive="377"

              minIdle="89"

              maxIdle="233"

              maxWait="10000"

              initialSize="34"

              removeAbandonedTimeout="100"

              removeAbandoned="true"

              suspectTimeout="60"

              abandonWhenPercentageFull="75"

              jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer"

              logAbandoned="true"

              minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"

              jmxEnabled="true"

              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

I'm using the recommended plugins configuration for 2.5.1. What is going wrong? How can I solve this error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129070/webapp-tomcat-jdbc-pooled-db-connection-throwing-abandon-exception

Answer (score 1):

I notice you have

```
logAbandoned = true
```

uncommented in your `DataSource.groovy` file, even thought the comment after it says:

> // causes stacktrace recording overhead, use only for debugging

Could it be, that the comment is correct, and it really does cause recording overhead? I'm just guessing...